# Should.js - Inconsistency in equals method should.equals

Tags: javascript, equals, should.js

I'm using the should.js framework (v8.2.x) to unit test and have been playing around with some very basic tests. However, I ran into this issue with the tests failing, which has stumped me.

I defined this dummy function to test, `add`:

```
var add = function(a, b) {
  if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
    throw new Error('One of the arguments is not a number');
  }
  return +a + +b
};
```

Now here're my dummy tests:

```
should.equal(add('1', '1'), '2');   // passes
add('1', '1').should.equal('2')     // fails!
```

Now according to their [github](https://github.com/shouldjs/should.js#shouldjs), `should(something)` and `something.should` usually return the same thing, but there's no additional info on the differences.

According to their [API documentation](https://shouldjs.github.io/#should-equal), `should.equal` is the same as `assert.equal`. But this test passes for me:

```
assert.equal(add('1','1'), '2'); // passes
```

**So I have three questions:**

1. Why does `add('1', '1').should.equal('2')` not pass?
2. Why are the two usages of should yielding different results?
3. Why do the docs say `should.equals` is the same as `assert.equals` when they actually have different behavior?

Comment: I'm guessing that one is using `==` and the other is using `===`. The `add` function is returning a `Number`, which you're comparing to a `string`. Perhaps the type coercion being done is different? What happens if you do `add('1', '1').should.equal(2)` instead?

Comment: What @ChrisTavares said, whenever you deal with testing numbers vs strings you've gotta check how the testing is performed, I would have assumed the test would return `'11'` for `'1' + '1'` but clearly it's not very literal.

Comment: @ChrisTavares Yes, the `equals` should use `==`, and `1 == '1'` in javascript. There's also `strictEquals` which uses `===`. `add('1', '1').should.equal(2)` does pass.

@brod If you look at `add`, I'm using the unary `+` operator to coerce them into Numbers.=

Comment: Are you sure about that? Check the docs & source code. The fact that `.should.equal(2)` passes seems to indicate that it's doing strict equality checking.

Comment: Exactly my issue... The docs also say that `should.equal` is the same as `assert.equal`, which I've tested to be utnrue.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions and what you got wrong.

> Now according to their github, should(something) and something.should usually return the same thing, but there's no additional info on the differences.

`should(something)` and `something.should` yes usually the same. But you used should.equal, docs says nothing about its equallity to other methods. It is just [copy of](https://github.com/shouldjs/should.js/blob/master/lib/ext/_assert.js#L105) node.js own [assert.equal](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/assert.js#L118)

> Why does add('1', '1').should.equal('2') not pass?

Because docs clearly said it uses === internally.

> Why are the two usages of should yielding different results?

Because that is different methods, and nowhere said it should be equal.

> Why do the docs say should.equals is the same as assert.equals when they actually have different behavior?

```
$ node
> var should = require('.')
undefined
> var assert = require('assert')
undefined
> var add = function(a, b) {
...   if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
.....     throw new Error('One of the arguments is not a number');
.....   }
...   return +a + +b
... };
undefined
> should.equal(add('1', '1'), '2');
undefined
> assert.equal(add('1', '1'), '2');
undefined
```

So to try clear what you got wrong: in should.js exists `should.equal(a, b)` which is the same as `assert.equal`. Also exists `something.should.equal(other)` which uses `===` internally (because exists `.eql` which do deep equal check), also `should(somethng).equal(other)` is the same as  `something.should.equal(other)` (but not for standard wrappers).

Hope it will make it clear.